# Best way to reverse the loop

Tags: loops, go, reverse

I am trying to learn Go. I have a block of code. For example, if I output the alphabet and want to make it reverse. How do I do it for the loop?

```
package main

import "github.com/01-edu/z01"

func main() {
    i := 97
    for i < 123 {
        z01.PrintRune(rune(i))
        i++
    }
    z01.PrintRune('\n')
}
```

P.S. I understood the code. Thanks all for your comments. I am not deleting, this thread might be useful for someone new in programming like me.

Comment: You loop from 97 up until 122, incrementing the loop variable. Change the 2 numbers and decrement instead of increment.

Comment: Instead of `for i := 97; i < 123; i++` use `for i := 123; i > 97; i--`.

Comment: @Flimzy `for i := 122; i >= 97; i-- {}`

Comment: @icza: You're right... the 2 hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-1 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I output the alphabet and want to make it reverse.

---

If you write the program in idiomatic Go, the solution should be obvious.

```
package main

import "github.com/01-edu/z01"

func main() {
    // forward
    for i := 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++ {
        z01.PrintRune(i)
    }
    z01.PrintRune('\n')

    // reverse
    for i := 'z'; i >= 'a'; i-- {
        z01.PrintRune(i)
    }
    z01.PrintRune('\n')
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/hPt7rqzxLok

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```